# TapGesture on webView

Tags: objective-c

I created a web view and loading a file on this. File may be in pdf, .doc, .docx. Next I added tapGesture on web view. Now if I click on web view tapGesture works only for pdf files.Its not worked for .doc, .docx files.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That may not be the actual problem. Please add some code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there any delay for touching the .doc file?

Comment: I added gesture in storyboard.@ Teja

Comment: No delay @ Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually my question is correct. Pdf had non-editable text but .doc , .docs had editable texts. So tapGesture is not working for .doc file. So in viewDidLoad I added this line

[webview.inputViewController  setEditing:NO];

After adding we need to implement this delegate method

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

  return YES;
  }